# Copying/Duplicating Sculpting Brushes

Tags: sculpting

I am uncertain how to make a copy of an already existing sculpt brush; I have been looking around on Google for tutorials on how to do this but all that shows up is how to delete duplicates instead of making duplicates.

What should I do to make duplicates?

Comment: The '+' button below the brush image on top of the panel (same principle as for materials, for instance)

Comment: Thank you so much for informing me; greatly appreciated! :)